# How do I update Unsubscribe Reason while importing in All Subscribers?

Tags: marketing-cloud, import

I am trying to update All Subscribers by importing a csv file. The file has Unsubscribe Reason as one of the column but when the import completes the Unsubscribe Reason column in All Subscribers doesn't get updated.

How do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Mark- I don't think Marketing Cloud has any workflows or triggers. You might be referring to Salesforce here which is not what the question is referring to.

Sanchit - I think that's the behavior of SFMC. When you import subscribers with 'Unsubscribed' status, it updates the status but the 'reason' value is set by default. In this case it will be 'Unsubscribed via Import'.  SFMC doesn't even give you the 'reason' field to map

Hope this helps